# Cancelar fila de eventos em Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos, fila

Então, eu tenho um loop que vai despertar umas 10 funções que são requisições AJAX, nas funções, o que engloba requisições AJAX é um `setTimeout()`, o que acontece é que, o loop é realizado na hora, e a cada 10 segundos(como determinei no `setTimeout()`) é executada uma função..

Mas, se eu quiser, abortar todas as funções(que já foram chamadas, só estão esperando o tempo para executarem, como determinei no `setTimeout`), o que eu poderia fazer?

Meu código tá +- assim:

```
$("array").each(function(i){
 setTimeout(function(){
  $.ajax({..});
 },5000*i);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro fazeres uma outra abordagem. Colocares uma chamada AJAX a iniciar a outra dentro da sua `success` function. Dessa maneira não gera chamadas em excesso.

De qq maneira e respondendo ao teu problema podes fazer assim:

```
var chamadas = {};
$("array").each(function (i) {
    chamadas[i] = setTimeout(function () {
        alert('AJAX!');
    }, 5000 * i);
});

// e quando precisares de cancelar
for (var nr in chamadas){
    clearTimeout(chamadas[nr]);
};

// ou se quiseres cancelar uma específica 
clearTimeout(chamadas[3]);
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta e pela sugestão, só ficou uma dúvida agora, será que da para pausar os `setTimeout`? A respeito da sugestão, eu vou aplicar na próxima vez o que chamam de promises e deferred, para mim ainda é um pouco confuso, mas quando eu aplicar talvez descomplique de vez..

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus não dá para pausar o `setTimeout`. Podes é ter um contador numa variável que é verificado por um relógio `setInterval` e nessa verificação tem um flag _pause / play_.  Algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/5ntqc993/

Comment: perfeito @Sergio, gostei do exemplo, vou acaba implementando algo assim na minha aplicação! abraços e sucesso.